# As I can get contacts that do not have associated client?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

there is my problem, I need to show all contact who do not have associated client. 
My dql is:

```
SELECT c FROM ComercialBundle:Contacto c WHERE c.cliente IS NULL
```

I get the next error:

```
A single-valued association path expression to an inverse side is not supported in DQL queries. Use an explicit join instead.
```

Entity assoc:

Contacto.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="CeiferIT\ComercialBundle\Entity\Cliente", mappedBy="contacto", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 **/
private $cliente;
```

Cliente.php

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="CeiferIT\ComercialBundle\Entity\Contacto", inversedBy="cliente", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="contacto_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $contacto;
```

How should I create my DQL?

Thank!

Comment: Please look at the documentation and existing questions before asking. 
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins

Comment: I have read the documentation but I have not found an answer to my question, so I opened this question, thanks for the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give to you the SQL query, you easily can make the DQL.

```
select c.* from Contacto c 
LEFT JOIN Cliente cc on cc.contacto_id = c.id
where cc.id is null
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Oh thank, My query has been as follows: 'SELECT c FROM ComercialBundle:Contacto c LEFT JOIN c.cliente cl WHERE cl.id IS NULL' and work!